# javascript - what kind of thing in a var

Tags: javascript

I've got either a literal object or one of it's components in var Z.  Ie. one of the following

```
var Q = {"name" : 123};

Z = Q; 
Z = Q["name"];
```

how can I determine which it is?

Answer (score 4):

If this case, you can use `typeof`<sup>[[mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof)]</sup> to check if the value is a number or not.

```
if (typeof z === "number") {
    alert("I'm the property!");
} else {
    alert("I'm the object!");
}
```

`typeof x` is useful if `x` is a primitive `"number"`, `"boolean"`, `"string"`, `"undefined"` or `"function"`, but you need more complicated checks for other types.

It's also possible for this check to behave unexpectedly if someone is using a object wrapper type instead of a primitive type. [patrick dw's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348109/javascript-what-kind-of-thing-in-a-var/7348639#7348639) provides a solution that can handle this.

Answer (score 2):

A safer and more versatile approach that `typeof` is to find out its internal *[[Class]]* property by calling `Object.prototype.toString` with `Z` set as the calling context, like this:

```
var type = Object.prototype.toString.call( Z );  // [object ???]
```

The result will be in the form of `[object Class]`, as in:

```
[object Object]
[object Array]
[object Number]
[object Boolean]
[object String]
```

You could easily make it into a function, something like this:

```
function getType( x ) {
    return x === void 0 ? 'undefined' :
           x === null ? 'null' :
           Object.prototype.toString.call( x ).slice( 8, -1 ).toLowerCase();
}
```

This will return a lowercase string result for the type you want:

```
"string"
"number"
"array"
// ...etc
```

I made explicit tests for `null` and `undefined` because I think there may be browser incompatibilities with those, but I'm not sure. Anyway, they're easy enough to test explicitly.

So then you'd use it like:

```
if( getType( Z ) === "string" ) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

The reason this is safer is that if a string for example happens to be given as its object wrapper, `typeof` will return `"object"` instead of `"string"`.

```
typeof new String("test");  // "object"
```

Also, it covers the case of `Array`, which will *always* return `"object"` with `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

use `typeof`

```
Z = Q; 
typeof Z == "object"; //true
Z = Q["name"];
typeof Q == "number"; //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the previous posts say, 'typeof' is the method you want.

It's worth knowing that typeof returns a string, even if the type is undefined or boolean for example so remember to use that in your checks.