# length property of Array.prototype object - ES 5

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

In `function` type objects, the `length` property signifies the number of arguments expected by a `function` type object. For example, the `length` field in `Function` object, `Array` object , in the below visualisation, has the value `1`.

[image]

In the above visualisation, `length` field is also a member of `object` type object `Array.prototype`, whose value is `0`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Properties) says:

> `Array.prototype.length` reflects the number of elements in an array.

Following this definition in below `cars` & `bikes` array,

```
var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
var bikes = ["Honda", "Yamaha"];
```

`cars.__proto__.length` & `bikes.__proto__.length`is still `0`.

Multiple array objects(`cars`, `bikes`) cannot share the same `length` property value as `length` property is sitting in `Array.prototype`.

1)

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Properties), Is it a right definition?

2)

If no, What does `length` field in `Array.prototype` signify?

Comment: Array.prototype.length is the number of elements in the array (sort of - sparse arrays and all that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MDN says:
>
> > *`Array.prototype.length` reflects the number of elements in an array.*
>
> Is it a right definition?

Sorta, yes. There are three different `.length` properties related to arrays:

- `Array.length`. As you said, it's an instance ("own") property that all *functions* have, and has nothing to do with arrays specifically.
- `arr.length`, where `arr` is an array instance (e.g. `arr = ['ex', 'ample']`). Every array has this [special property](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.2) that acts a bit like a getter/setter, automatically determining the highest array index property that the object has.
- `Array.prototype.length` is a special case of #2, as `Array.prototype` is just an array object itself - empty by default, therefore `.length == 0`.

MDN is a bit inaccurate because it mixes instance properties with those inherited from the prototype in its documentation pages. As your diagram correctly visualises, all of the `cars`, `bikes` and `Array.prototype` objects do have their own `.length` property with its own value (and changing one doesn't change the others of course).

So what purpose does `Array.prototype.length` have? Not much, actually, as it's typically shadowed by an own property of the array objects that inherit from `Array.prototype`. So apart from just being there because the spec says that `Array.prototype` is an array instance and those have that property, it can also serve as a sensible default `.length` value on *normal* (non-array) objects that inherit from `Array.prototype` - those cases are very rare though.

Comment: `Array.prototype` is just an array instance itself?  As this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11541474) says:*When you put something on the prototype, every instance of the object shares the same code for the method.* What do you mean, when you say, `Array.prototype` is array instance? I am not getting this point.

Comment: Yes, it is. Admittedly, one that does not inherit from itself of course, and one that has lots of odd properties (all the Array methods), but it's still an array object in the meaning that it has this special-working `.length` property.

Comment: `Array.prototype` is an array object in the meaning that it has `.length` property? It is hard to accept this. Using object literal notation, If I say,  `xyz { length : 2 }`, Is `xyz` an array object? `xyz` and `Array.prototype` are both `object` type.

Comment: No, the emphasis is on *special* `.length` property. And it also has its internal *[[class]]* set to `"Array"`. See [ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4): "*The Array prototype object is itself an array; its [[Class]] is "Array", and it has a length property (whose initial value is +0) and the special [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method*".

Comment: What is the syntax to find [[Class]] of length property?

Comment: @overexchange: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7348639/1048572). The *[[class]]* of `Array.prototype` is `"Array"`, `Array.prototype.length` does not have a *[[class]]* as it is a primitive number.

Comment: Answer talks about typeof operator. Applying typeof to Array.prototype gives 'object' type.

Comment: @overexchange: The answer I linked to talks about `Object.prototype.toString.call`, not `typeof`.

Comment: OK. So, How can i make `.length` of `Array.prototype`more than 0?

Comment: @overexchange: Just `Array.prototype.length = 1` or `.length++` or `Array.prototype[0] = "something"` etc… `Array.prototype` is a fully-functioning array!

Comment: So, In addition to having your own array object(like `cars` & `bikes` in my question), what was the idea to provide `Array.prototype` as a fully functioning array? Is there a scenario, where such usage is required?

Comment: See [Why Array.prototype is an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23652338/1048572), basically the answer is "why not?". You might want to ask the language designers.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"); 
> var bikes = ["Honda", "Yamaha"];
> ```
>
> `cars.__proto__.length` & `bikes.__proto__.length` is still 0.

Yes, but `cars.length === 3` and `bikes.length === 2`.

`cars.__proto__.length` is the length of the `prototype` property of the `Array` constructor function. Which is an empty array instance by default.

**Details**

`Array.prototype` is an empty array instance.
`var cars = new Array()` results in an object with the `__proto__` pointing to `Array.prototype`.
So `cars.__proto__ === Array.prototype`.

On an array instance, `length` is the value of the largest integer property on the Array object, plus one. Or zero if it is empty.

```
var a = [];
a[10] = 'foo';
a.length; // 11
```

`Array.prototype` is empty.

Hence

```
cars.__proto__.length === 0
```

Comment: 1) I did not get you, when you say, *`cars.__proto__.length` is the length of the `prototype` property of the `Array` constructor function.* What does it mean to say `length` of `Array.prototype` property? ####  2) `Array.prototype` is empty? What does this mean?